# Splitting a column in a DataFrame based on multiple possible delimiters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have an address column in a dataframe in pandas with 3 types of information namely street, colony and city.

There are three values with two possible delimiters - either a ',' or a white-space e.g it can be either `Street1,Colony1,City1` or `Street1 Colony1 City1`.

I need to split this column into three with respective labels `'Street'`,`'Colony'` and `'City'` with the values from this `Address` column split accordingly.

What is the most efficient way to do this as the pandas `split` function only allows you with a single delimiter or a regex expression (maybe a regex expression for this as I'm not very good with regex).

Answer (score 6):

If you are certain it is either a comma `,` or a whitespace  you could use:

```
df[['Street','Colony','City']] = df.address.str.split('[ ,]', expand=True)
```

---

**Explanation:** [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) accepts a pat (pattern) parameter: String or **regular expression** to split on. If not specified, split on whitespace. Using the fact we can pass a regular expression this becomes an easy task as `[ ,]` in regex means either  or `,`.

An alternative would be to use `' |,'` or if you can have multiple whitespace `'\s+|,'`

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'address': ['a,b,c','a b c']
})

df[['Street','Colony','City']] = df.address.str.split('[ ,]', expand=True)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  address Street Colony City
0   a,b,c      a      b    c
1   a b c      a      b    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
df[['Street','Colony','City']] = df.address.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(re.split('\W',x)))
```

`\W` will match any character which is not word character. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re)

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this would be to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to consolidate your delimiters, then use `str.split` on that single delimiter to create your new columns.

```
import pandas as pd 
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':['Street1,Colony1,City1',  'Street2 Colony2 City2']})

location_df = (df.address
                 .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(re.sub(pattern=' |,', 
                                                   repl=',', 
                                                   string=x).split(','), 
                                            index=['street','colony','city']))
                )
```