# Split one colum into two by multiple delimiter characters in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

For a example dataframe has `words` column, I want to split each row by either `llo` or `lut`, into two columns: `words1` and `words2`.

```
                 words
0           helloworld
1          hellomadame
2           salutmonde
3          salutmadame
4    englishhelloworld
5   englishhellomadame
6   francaissalutmonde
7  francaissalutmadame
```

How could I get the follow output? Thank you.

```
          words1  words2
0          hello   world
1          hello  madame
2          salut   monde
3          salut  madame
4   englishhello   world
5   englishhello  madame
6  francaissalut   monde
7  francaissalut  madame
```

I try with `df.words.str.split('llo | lut', expand=True)`, but it doesn't work out. Someone could help? Many thanks.

```
                     0
0           helloworld
1          hellomadame
2           salutmonde
3          salutmadame
4    englishhelloworld
5   englishhellomadame
6   francaissalutmonde
7  francaissalutmadame
```

Comment: You may get the result using a single call to `Series.str.split`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110177/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with added space after strings `llo` or `lut` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df['words'].str.replace('(llo|lut)', r'\1 ', n=1).str.split(expand=True)
df.columns=['words1','words2']
print (df)
          words1           words2
0          hello            world
1          hello           madame
2          salut            monde
3          salut           madame
4   englishhello            world
5   englishhello           madame
6  francaissalut            monde
7  francaissalut           madame
```

Comment: Thank you, what `r'\1 '` stands for here?

Comment: @ahbon - it is reference to `(llo|lut)` - add space after `llo` or `lut`

Comment: One problem, in my real data, it was split into three columns. And how can split and set names instead of `add_prefix`?

Comment: @ahbon - I think problem should be multiple `llo` or `lut`, if want split by first `llo` or `lut` use `df = df['words'].str.replace('(llo|lut)', r'\1 ', n=1).str.split(expand=True).add_prefix('words')`

Comment: Get it, and how can I split and set names instead of `add_prefix`?

Comment: @ahbon - I think simpliest is assign new columns by list, answer was edited.

Comment: Sorry, in my data there are others columns besides `words`, so I don't want to set `df['words'].str.replace('(llo|lut)', r'\1 ', n=1).str.split(expand=True)` as `df`. Can I split `words` while keeping other columns?

Comment: @ahbon - Sure, use `df[['words1','words2']] = df['words'].str.replace('(llo|lut)', r'\1 ', n=1).str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: Cool and awsome as always. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, one more question why can't use `'[llo|lut]'` instead of `'(llo|lut)'` here? It works at this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794287/splitting-a-column-in-a-dataframe-based-on-multiple-possible-delimiters

Comment: @ahbon - Unfortunately I am not regex expert, so no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

Not a very Pythonic and efficient solution, but this will do the job

```
df = df.words.str.split('(llo|lut)', expand=True)
df[0] = df[0] + df[1]
df = df.drop(1, axis = 1)
df = df.rename(columns = {0 : "words1", 2 : "words2"})
```

This will output

```
    words1             words2
0   hello              world
1   hello              madame
2   salut              monde
3   salut              madame
4   englishhello       world
5   englishhello       madame
6   francaissalut      monde
7   francaissalut      madame
```

In rename, the dictionary keys had to be 0 and 2, because after concatenation, the dataframe looks like

```
    0              1    2
0   hello          llo  world
1   hello          llo  madame
2   salut          lut  monde
3   salut          lut  madame
4   englishhello   llo  world
5   englishhello   llo  madame
6   francaissalut  lut  monde
7   francaissalut  lut  madame
```

And after dropping column 1, it becomes

```
    0               2
0   hello           world
1   hello           madame
2   salut           monde
3   salut           madame
4   englishhello    world
5   englishhello    madame
6   francaissalut   monde
7   francaissalut   madame
```

The column names are 0 and 2, hence renaming of 0 and 2 is done. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single regex to split the column:

```
(?<=l(?:lo|ut))
(?<=llo|lut)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EA5mkA/1). The pattern is a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `llo` or `lut`.

Python demo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"words": ["helloworld","hellomadame","salutmonde","salutmadame","englishhelloworld","englishhellomadame","francaissalutmonde","francaissalutmadame"]})

df = df['words'].str.split(r'(?<=l(?:lo|ut))', expand=True)
df.columns=['words1','words2']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          words1  words2
0          hello   world
1          hello  madame
2          salut   monde
3          salut  madame
4   englishhello   world
5   englishhello  madame
6  francaissalut   monde
7  francaissalut  madame
```